# Number of infinite trees on certain cardinal

Tags: set-theory, trees, infinitary-combinatorics

Let $\kappa$ be some infinite cardinal. I usually use the notation $\langle T,<_T\rangle$ to refer to a tree. My question is: what is the number of non-isomorphic trees with $|T|=\kappa$?

There is an easy upper bound: $<_T\subseteq T\times T$, then, $<_T\in\mathcal{P}(T\times T)$, therefore, there are no more than $2^\kappa$-many non-isomorphic trees with cadinality $\kappa$. But, is this an optimal bound? Is it possible to define a tree for each element of $\mathcal{P}(T\times T)$? This question seems very basic and simple to me, however, I have not been able to find the answer anywhere. I suspect it may be independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, but I have no idea.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a set $S\subseteq\kappa$, consider the tree $T_S$ that has a maximal branch of length $\alpha$ iff $\alpha\in\kappa$. Concretely we can set $$T_S=\{f\in\kappa^{<\kappa}: f(0)\in S, length(f)<f(0), i>0\rightarrow f(i)=0\}.$$ Then clearly $T_S\cong T_{S'}$ iff $S=S'$.

*(Fine, I technically need to restrict to $S\subseteq\kappa\setminus\{0\}$ and require $\vert S\vert=\kappa$, but there are again $2^\kappa$-many such subsets of $\kappa$ so that's benign.)*

Comment: Thank you, but I have a question: how do we see that $|T_S|=\kappa$?

Comment: @Yester If $|S|=\kappa$, then the least node of $T_S$ has $\kappa$ many immediate successors so $|T_S|=\kappa$.

Comment: @HanulJeon Actually I might have overshot if GCH fails; I've added a clause to keep the size of $T_S$ small.